# Problem in accessing data form Landsat5 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5

I have written a code to calculate NDWI from LANDSAT5 and to creat a time series chart. 
the problem is that I get very weird results- it says there are only 2 images  between 1990-2011 and for that reason I get wrong graph.
 what can be the reason? is this data is blocked for use or there is something wrong in my code?

this is the code I have written:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1990-01-01', '2011-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});


// Get the number of images.
var count = clippedCol.size();
print('Count: ',count);
//print(clippedCol);
print(dataset,'dataset');



//function to calculate NDWI in LANDSAT5
var addNDWI = function(image) {
  var NDWI = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B5'])
  .rename('NDWI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(NDWI);

};

//NDWI to the clipped image collection
var withNDWI = clippedCol.map(addNDWI).select('NDWI');

var NDWIcolor = {
  min: -1,
  max:1,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};

var listOfImages =(withNDWI.toList(withNDWI.size()));
var randomImage=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
Map.centerObject(geometry,12);
Map.addLayer(randomImage,NDWIcolor,'Random_Image_test');

print(ui.Chart.image.series(withNDWI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
```

Comment: can you specify your geometry? i tried using your code with my own point I get 224 images.

Comment: it's an area in Nigeria